# Structure of first database design

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I’m trying to create a database where the operator (me in this case) receives a log and then assigns multiple people to review this log based on the various subsystems they represent. So for example, a test is run called x. Once x is run, I receive the log of x and assign five people representing different subsystems to review it. What I’m trying to do is manage all the reviews and see if any reviews are outstanding. The structure I was hoping for, and what I have implemented so far consists of the following: I have two forms in which to enter data, one for the run information that I enter, and one for the reviews that the other people enter. The problem I’m running into is how I’m able to view who has done each review. Below is a picture of the relationships I have of my database (the two letter acronyms represent the subsystems I’m assigning):

[image]

I originally was thinking about creating a query where I would be able to search by last name and show who had done what review based on whether or not they had checked the Done Review box on the review form. The problem with this was that unless a person created a review then a review wouldn’t exist at all so I wouldn’t be able to query whether or not they had completed it based on the check box. The other idea that I had was to add a check box for each sub system in the run information table and then map the check box in the review form to that check box in the run information table based on the RUN ID and Domain info they entered into the review form. I haven’t been successful in that either as I haven’t found a way to dynamically update the control source of the check box in the review form. Anybody have any ideas of how’d they’d implement this or something I’m missing? This is my first dealing with database development and I’m at a loss right now. Thanks.

Comment: If this first dealing with database, i advice reading  a book and start practice: https://www.amazon.com/Beginning-C-Databases-Novice-Professional/dp/1590594339

Answer (score -1):

The tables have one-many relationship , you can use Ms-Access to build your tables, queries and master /detail form by wizard.

You can  modify it by vba code.

At least you get starting system.

**Edit:**

Master form: RunInformation

Detail Form: Review

Link join field between master/detail: RunId

in this case , for any RunInformation in master form , you can insert the five records assignment for each sub system

You can do all CRUD operation for master/detail

q: "What I’m trying to do is manage all the reviews and see if any reviews are outstanding."

A: add a button in the master form that filter master/detail form  where status is "oustanding".

Note:

Modify structure of "RunInformation"  and remove columns of the subsystem (like hw,sw,..),and add status column in the "review" Table and column for the subsystem (hw,sw). 
You can do it as combo box in Review form, and status as checkbox.

Comment: I preferred this solution based on OP saying"This is my first dealing with database development and I’m at a loss right now.."; and this approach help him and TAGS of question is ms-acess vba.